# Нужна ли запятая после ПОТОМУ?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Мифы продолжают жить в ряде работ не только потому, что их авторы недостаточно знакомы с историей вопроса, но иногда и потому(,) что они оказываются неспособны взглянуть на исследуемую проблему под иным углом, становясь пленниками определенных методологических установок.
Нужна ли запятая в скобках?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь сложный союз **потому что** попадает под условия расчленения (см. ниже цитату из Розенталя), поэтому нужна запятая перед **что**.

> К условиям расчленения сложного союза относятся:
>   ...
>   4) включение
>   первой части (соотносительного слова) в ряд однородных членов
>   предложения или параллельных конструкций: *Хозяйственная часть в доме
>   Пшеницыной процветала не  потому только, что Агафья Матвеевна была
>   образцовая хозяйка, но и потому ещё, что Иван Матвеевич Мухояров был в
>   гастрономическом отношении великий эпикуреец (Гонч.)*;

Answer (score 0):

"Потому что", как правило, выделяется запятыми; возможно выделение как перед оборотом, так и после него.

Запятая перед оборотом здесь исключается, следовательно - нужна запятая после.

Comment: *"Потому что", как правило, выделяется запятыми* — двумя? Ещё не совсем понятно, что Вы называете "оборотом" и где находится Ваше "после оборота".